# Anyone know a good resource for MVC3 and Jquery with parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to do some jquery.post where I pass back the Model. I been searching google but can't really find a detail example of $.post with data that passes back Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a strongly typed view with a model you could use the $.ajax method to send your entire model to the server using a JSON AJAX request:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Foo")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({ model: model }),
        success: function(result) {
            // TODO: process the result from the server
        }
    });
</script>
```

and the corresponding controller action to which we send the POST request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel model)
{
    // TODO: do something with the request and return a result
}
```

Comment: I get a circular reference at Json.Encode(Model). MyViewModel has a property for the Model. And the Model class were generated via Linq to Sql. Is this because of the reference tables?

Comment: @jmogera, you should never pass domain models (such as Linq-To-SQL classes) to your views. You should only use view models which are classes that you specifically define for each view in order to meet its requirements.

Comment: Thank. I am new to this, but I have create properties that only apply to the views, and is not passing the model properties to the view. The event you have listed above does get called, but the "MyViewModel" has null references. I have set up @Html.TextBorFor(x => x.Property1). When I enter txt into the field and press the button, the Property1 doesn't get updated. Any idea why the whole object in the parameter is coming as null?

Comment: @jmogera, what are you talking about? Show your code? I don't have a magic crystal ball that allows me to read your mind.

Comment: sorry about that, I should just post my code. I got it working. Basically data: 'JSON.stringify({ **model**: model })', and 'public ActionResult Foo(MyViewModel **model**)' needed to match up. The parameter for Foo was not the same on my end. Resolved it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @Darin, sorry to bother you man. But can you help me with the behavior [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653120/ajax-post-back-not-working-correctly) Basically I followed the example you gave, but first time submit, the viewmodel is still coming null, and second time it works fine. As explained in the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

Home this helps

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dorischen/archive/2011/02/28/mvc-amp-jquery-webcamp-presentation-demo-and-labs-are-available.aspx